# Add javascript condition inside text variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code working fine but I wanna simplify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function RenderPager(items) {

      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

         var li = "<li";

         if(i == 0){
            li += " class='first'";
         }

         li +=">" + i + "</li>";

         // do something else
      }
   }
</script>
```

I would like to have condition inline something like this:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

       var li = "<li" + if(i == 0){ li += " class='first'" }; + ">" + i + "</li>";

       // do something else
   }
```

But this is not working and I tried everything but I don't know how to combine javascript condition in text variable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (`?..:`), also known as the ternary operator:

```
var li = "<li" + (i == 0 ? " class='first'" : "") + ">" + i + "</li>";
```

Also note, this could probably also be done using a little CSS with the [`:fist-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo-class, but it's not supported by older versions of IE. See this [compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/):

```
li:first-child {
    /* applies only to the first <li> element in a list */
}
```

Comment: Alternatively this shorter version would work also `(!i && ' class="first"' || '')`.